# Is it possible to declare types in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am wanting to clarify if it is not possible to declare types in Ruby or is it just not necessary? If someone wanted to declare datatypes would it be possible.

Update: My point in asking is to understand if providing a static type for variables that won't change type will provide a performance increase, in theory.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Some languages as C or Java use “strong” or “static” variable typing. Ruby is a “dynamically typed” language aka "duck typing", which means that variable dynamically changes its own type when type of assigned data has changed.

So, you can't declare variable to some strict type, it will always be dynamic.

Comment: I can surely control what data type each variable contains,  I would just have to keep aware of this ad not change the type. Are there other ruby feature that depend on dynamic typing being enabled?

Comment: Your answer will be more precise if you avoided to use strong and static typing as having a similar meaning. Ruby is a dynamically typed language while being a strong typed one at the same time.

Answer (score 6):

What are you trying to do?

You can create your own class:

```
class Boat
end
```

If you want an easy way to make a class for holding data, use a struct:

```
class Boat < Struct.new(:name, :speed)
end
b = Boat.new "Martha", 31
```

You can NOT declare the class of a variable or method argument, like you can in C.  Instead, you can check the type at run time:

```
b.is_a?(Boat)    # Includes subclasses of Boat
b.class == Boat
```

Comment: At the time I was thinking it would give the interpreter something less to do and possibly speed things along.

Answer (score 6):

One proposal to add typing to Ruby is http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5583 by Yasushi Ando (of [parse.y famtour](http://rubykaigi.org/2011/en/schedule/details/18S01) fame). My favorite comment was:

> (b) not sure how it can honor duck typing. i think the whole idea is
>   to (optionally) roast the duck!

Answer (score 2):

If I correctly understood what you mean with `type`, each `Class` in Ruby defines a type.

```
1.class
# => Fixnum
```

You can create a class to define a custom type

```
class Book
end

b = Book.new
b.class
# => Book
```